# pg_dump: symbol lookup error: pg_dump: undefined symbol: PQconnectdbParams

Tags: postgresql

I just installed *PostgreSQL 8.4* and then installed *PostgreSQL 9.0*. I am using *PostgreSQL 9.0* services but I can't run *pg_dump*.

I get the error:

> pg_dump: server version: 9.0.12; pg_dump version: 8.4.13

So I replaced the *pg_dump* located in */user/lib* with *pg_dump 9.0* and am getting the error:

> pg_dump: symbol lookup error: pg_dump: undefined symbol:

Comment: Don't move executables around. Fix your path instead.

Comment: There's a great deal of info that *isn't* here. How you installed each PostgreSQL version, why, and from where. Your operating system and version. etc. However, you've already caused chaos by moving executables and libraries around - *don't do that*. So it's going to be hard to diagnose and fix even with the details that aren't here.  It's certain that `pg_dump` is linking to the wrong `libpq`, but beyond that ... *shrug*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Version Different so it will be done by using take dump in sql format and restore in to PostgreSQL sql 9.0